# Curiosity: why the shift operators have less priority than the additive?

Tags: c#, operators, bit-shift

I'm wondering why the shift operators (<< and >>), being equivalent to a multiplication and a division respectively, do have less priority than an additive operator, such the "+".

In other words:

```
int a = 1 + 2 * 8;  //yields 17
```

whereas:

```
int a = 1 + 2 << 3; //yields 24
```

Anyone knows what's the reason behind this behavior?

NOTE: Please, don't answer me "because the specs say so"!

Thank you all in advance.

EDIT: I realized that a left-shift can be obtained by summing the left operand by itself. May be this the reason?

Comment: Bit shifting is _not_ multiplication. It can be used in certain circumstances to have the same effect as a multiplication by a power of two but the goals are entirely different. You can't multiply by 47, for example, without some long-winded shift-and-accumulate algorithm.

Comment: Fully respect your viewpoint, but the bitwise shifting *IS* mathematically a multiplication, although you cannot specify whatever factors you want. Better: there's a power involved too, thus the precedence should be even higher.

Comment: The _goal_ of bitshifting is to shift bits, not multiply. I can multiply a number by three simply by adding it to itself twice (`a = a + a + a`) but that doesn't morph the intent of the `+` operator into multiplication. It also doesn't magically shift `+` up the precedence table :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The relative priority of arithmetic operators and bitwise operators is irrelevant because *you should never be using them together anyway.* If you want to treat an integer as an array of bits, then don't be adding and subtracting it like a number. If you want to treat an integer as a number, then don't be shifting, or-ing and and-ing it like an array of bits.

Frankly if I had my way there would be no bit shifting operations on integers; you'd have to cast the integer to a BitArray type, that would not have arithmetic on it. The fact that ints are treated as both bit arrays and numbers is an unfortunate design flaw that exists for historical reasons.

The notion that bit shifting is a kind of multiplication and division is a strange one; bit shifting is bit shifting, not multiplication.

Comment: Now, I would absolutely love implementing AES with your int/BitArray distinction. The reason both bitwise and arithmetic operations are possible on ints is not a "historic" one, but simply because the hardware supports both interchangeably, and there are tons of good reasons to do both. Even outside of cryptography.

Comment: @Dolda2000: Why should *what some hardware does* have even the slightest impact on *what some programming language does*? Programming languages are no longer thin layers on top of assembly code; it is an accident of history that C# is a descendent of C, and that C was implemented on hardware that doesn't distinguish between arrays of bits and numbers. We use bits because it happens to be convenient; had it been historically convenient for hardware to use three-state "bits" instead of two-state bits then bit-shifting would *not* be multiplying by two.

Comment: Shame on me: I'd had to think it better, before posting such a question. That's absolutely true from a high-level language perspective.
BTW, about the AND-izing context, I agree again, thus we should use the Enum.HasFlag method instead of treat it as an int...

Comment: Personally I think all different operators should always be parenthesised, e.g. `(a + b) - c`, and that binary operators shouldn't have priority. Sometimes (e.g. `a + b * c`) it makes perfect sense, and sometimes (e.g. `a + b << c` or `a | b & c`) there's just no default for us to consider. These cases should at least be a compiler warning if not an error. Of course, that would have to have been decided quite a few years ago...

Comment: @EricLippert: I have a vague memory of some part of C# being ugly *for the sake of hardware*, and there being an annotation in the spec to that effect. Possibly the fact that shifts are masked to 32 or 64 bits? Will check when I get the chance. Or I could have misremembered...

Comment: @JonSkeet: There are of course any number of places where the hardware influences the language design. The design of "volatile" is motivated entirely by weak processor memory models. The fact that floating point operations are sometimes higher-precision than specified. And so on. But there are lots of ways in which "being close to the hardware" influenced C that we've abandoned in C#; the most obvious of which being that the fundamental tool for indirection -- the reference -- is no longer a first-class data type that is convertible to integer.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: The fact that there is no hardware that does distinguish between bit arrays and numbers may be relevant to the fact. Just because it is possible to imagine hardware that does, doesn't actually make it relevant.

Comment: @Dolda2000, but that doesn't stop you to make two types, say `Integer32` and `BitArray32`, use them differently in your language, but represent them both as 32-bit integers when compiled to assembly.

Comment: Well I don't know about you guys, but I *want* to mix bitwise and arithmetic operators. Not all the time of course, but `x & -x` and `x & (x - 1)` are pretty important. Of course it's possible to do them the slow way, but that way is, you know, slow. I guess things like that could be built into the `BitArray32` type, but seeing as that wasn't done, I'll keep mixing.

Comment: @svick: Of course it doesn't stop you, but nothing obliges you to either. Why enforce arbitrary restrictions on programmers for which there is no use?

Comment: @Dolda2000: My guess the arbitrary restriction would serve a similar purpose as the units of measure do in F#.  Allowing the type system to protect you from mixing the wrong bits together.

Comment: I came across this thread, and as a C++ developer I think it's absolutely hilarious how you C# devs are so scared of bitwise operations. Bitwise maths has many uses, from hardware emulators to image processing. I'm surprised you have dismissed such a useful tool.

Answer (score 7):

If I were to ascribe a rational decision to it, I'd say it's because convenient in some common situations, such as when constructing bit patterns: `A + B << 8` would mark bits A and B in the second-to-least significant byte.

It could just as well just be a random priority allocation as well, of course, because Dennis Ritchie didn't have any idea where it would fit better (I blatantly assume C# inherits the operator priorities from C). Unfortunately, he isn't here to tell us anymore. :(

Comment: Yeah, I'll mourn Ritchie a little more than Jobs. Jobs' greatest achievement (IMO) was Pixar rather than Apple. The last good thing out of Apple was the `Apple ][e` :-)